# Changing yahoo messanger's status using mac terminal

Tags: terminal

Does anybody know how I can change my yahoo messenger's status using a command in mac terminal !? Or anything except the regular way to change it !?
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to see if ["Automator" would allow you to automate it](http://maketecheasier.com/create-basic-script-with-automator/2009/09/03), but I don't see any cmd line parameters to messenger on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Messenger doesn’t provide an automation mechanism, however not all is lost. You can set set a keyboard shortcut for the statuses (they are in the menu) so you could do this:

Go to System Preferences, Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts, then from the list select “Application Shortcuts" then click “+” to add a new one.

[image]

Select Yahoo Messenger and **type the name of the command exactly as it appears in the yahoo statuses menu**. It is *case sensitive*. A simple typo will cause the shortcut to fail.

I.e.: “Busy" is not the same as "busy”.

Then set a key combination:

Look at mine:

[image]

**DRAWBACK**: You need to have Yahoo active (i.e. focus) so the menu displayed belongs to yahoo. That means is not a “global shortcut”.

**PLUS**: This method is useful for any other application/Command.